# Writing code to retrieve data from a spreadsheet

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with a spreadsheet on aquaculture in Norway. where each row contains different pieces of information for a specific company (goal, specie, address, etc). I'm trying to write a piece of code that prints out the number of companies working on each species of marine life. This is what I have so far

```
import csv

species = []

with open('Akvakulturregisteret.csv', newline='', encoding='iso-8859-1') as csvfile:
    akvareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in akvareader:    
        try:
            specie = row[-13]
        except ValueError:
            continue
        species.append(specie)

species = list(dict.fromkeys(species))
species.remove("")
species.remove("ART")

companies = []


with open('Akvakulturregisteret.csv', newline='', encoding='iso-8859-1') as csvfile:
    akvareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for i in range(len(species)):
        for row in akvareader:
            if row[-13] == species[i]:
                company = row[2]
                companies.append(company)
                             
companies = list(dict.fromkeys(companies))         
print(len(companies))
```

Where the first with open part creates a list of all the different species.  ['Regnbueørret', 'Ørret', 'Laks', .....] However, the second part only gives the number of companies working on the first element of the list. It seems like it stops after the first element and doesn't iterate over the whole list. Any help or feedback is appreciated.

The CSV file looks like this (this is one column)

```
A A 0001;969159570;NORGES MILJØ- OG BIOVITENSKAPELIGE;POSTBOKS 5003;1432;ÅS;03-10
1991;;3021;ÅS;Kommersiell;MATFISK;Regnbueørret;000;TN;10362;NERFJØSET;3021;ÅS;LAND;FERSKVANN;6
```

You can see the whole thing here https://www.fiskeridir.no/Akvakultur/Registre-og-skjema/Akvakulturregisteret . if you scroll all the way down there is a link

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample of the data, for example 2 or 3 rows of the CSV file.

Comment: I added one row of the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use `defaultdict` from `collections` and use the species as the key and `set()` as your default value and then add companies to it. Finally, put `len()` on the companies and you have (I assume) what you want.

Here's how:

```
import collections
import csv


with open("Akvakulturregisteret.csv", newline="", encoding="iso-8859-1") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    output = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for row in reader:
        company, species = row[2], row[12]
        output[species].add(company)

for species, companies in dict(output).items():
    print(f"{species} - {len(companies)}")
```

This prints species and number of companies dealing with it.

```
Laks - 315
Ørret - 306
Regnbueørret - 305
Rognkjeks (felles) - 48
Gressgylt - 15
Tunge - 9
Grønngylt - 15
Trepigget stingsild - 6
Rødspette - 15
Gapeflyndre - 3
Havabbor - 4
Sandflyndre - 4
Piggvar - 17
Berggylt - 32
Bergnebb - 18
and so on...
```

And if you want that sorted, use this:

```
import collections
import csv

with open("Akvakulturregisteret.csv", newline="", encoding="iso-8859-1") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    output = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for row in reader:
        company, species = row[2], row[12]
        output[species].add(company)

data = {
    k: len(v) for k, v in
    sorted(output.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
}

for species, companies in data.items():
    print(f"{species} - {companies}")
```

Output:

```
Laks - 315
Ørret - 306
Regnbueørret - 305
Torsk - 56
Sukkertare - 55
Butare - 50
Blåskjell - 49
Rognkjeks (felles) - 48
Fingertare - 45
Søl - 40
Østers - 37
Havsalat - 33
Berggylt - 32
Kamskjell - 31
Røye - 27
Kveite - 25
Stortare - 24
Hummer - 22
Fjærehinne uspes - 21
...
```

Comment: That's correct, thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Referencing from your code, you don't need to use a list of dictionaries, you can use just one dictionary to hold the specie names as keys and number of companies working on them as values.

So in your first file open you read the species put them in the dictionary and initialize the values to zero, and the second one reads the companies and increases the value of each specie.

```py
import csv

species = dict()

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:    
        try:
            specie = row[-13]

        except ValueError:
            continue
        species[specie] = []

print("Len {0}".format(len(species)))

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        for key in species:
            if key == row[-13]:
                species[key].append(row[2]) 

for k, v in dict(species).items():
    print("Number of companies working on {0} is {1}".format(k, len(v)))
```

If the csv file is huge I would recommend changing your approach and not read the file twice.